# How to reduce the font size in table?

Tags: tables, two-column

I am using the following code in the class elsarticle, in this table the size of the font(numbers etc) is larger. I want to extend the width of the table to full-text width also. Can anyone suggests how to do that, I tried `\small` \tiny not working here.

```
\begin{table}
    
    \caption{The proposed method performance using MNIT-SEHSD Datset}
    \label{mnit_per}
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
        
        \begin{tabular}{l c c c }
    
            \hline
            Emotion&Precision&Recall&F1 Score\\
            \hline
            Neutral&  0.94  & 0.97  & 0.95\\
            Angry  &  0.95  & 0.96  & 0.95\\
            Happy  &  0.95  & 0.95  & 0.95 \\
            Fear   &  0.90  & 0.96  & 0.93\\
            Sad    &  1.00  & 0.90  & 0.95 \\
            \hline
            
            
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Please tell us whether you use the `elsarticle` document class with the option `1p`, `3p`, or `5p`, and whether you employ a one-column or a two-column layout.

Comment: Start by removing the `\resizebox` command. As you discovered, resizing tables leads to inconsistent font sizes throughout the document. If your table is then narrower than the desired width, give `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c c c }` a try. (Although personally, I recommend not to stretch a table to a width wider than its natrual width, since it won't improve the readability of the table.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For table you may consider to use `tabularray` and `booktabs` package (latter is loaded as library) and use `X` column type for the last three columns. Using them table width will be equal to column width with equal widths of the last three columns:

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle} % two-column layout
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption} % for better control over caption, if needed
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{The proposed method performance using MNIT-SEHSD Datset}
    \label{mnit_per}

    \begin{tblr}{ l X[c] X[c] X[c] }
        \toprule
    Emotion&Precision&Recall&F1 Score\\
        \midrule
    Neutral&  0.94  & 0.97  & 0.95 \\
    Angry  &  0.95  & 0.96  & 0.95 \\
    Happy  &  0.95  & 0.95  & 0.95 \\
    Fear   &  0.90  & 0.96  & 0.93 \\
    Sad    &  1.00  & 0.90  & 0.95 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you do *not* want to change the font size used in the table (and why should you?), don't touch use one of the commands that changes the (relative or absolute) font size. Also, *under no circumstance* should you touch `\resizebox` if the goal is to make the table fit inside the allocated space.

Instead, consider replacing the `tabular` environment with a `tabular*` environment and setting the overall width of the `tabular*` environment to `\linewidth`. (`\columnwidth` will do too.) The following screenshot shows the outputs of the `tabular` and `tabular*` approaches.

[image]

```
\documentclass[5p]{elsarticle} % two-column layout

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{The proposed method performance using MNIT-SEHSD Datset}
    \label{mnit_per}
    
    \smallskip
    
    \begin{tabular}{ l ccc }
            \hline
            Emotion&Precision&Recall&F1 Score\\
            \hline
            Neutral&  0.94  & 0.97  & 0.95 \\
            Angry  &  0.95  & 0.96  & 0.95 \\
            Happy  &  0.95  & 0.95  & 0.95 \\
            Fear   &  0.90  & 0.96  & 0.93 \\
            Sad    &  1.00  & 0.90  & 0.95 \\
            \hline
    \end{tabular}
    
    \bigskip
    
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l ccc }
            \hline
            Emotion&Precision&Recall&F1 Score\\
            \hline
            Neutral&  0.94  & 0.97  & 0.95 \\
            Angry  &  0.95  & 0.96  & 0.95 \\
            Happy  &  0.95  & 0.95  & 0.95 \\
            Fear   &  0.90  & 0.96  & 0.93 \\
            Sad    &  1.00  & 0.90  & 0.95 \\
            \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```